# Странное поведение - компилятор игнорирует конструктор копирования и пытается вызвать удаленный конструктор перемещения

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, конструктор-копирования

Рассмотрим следующий код (реальный код несколько сложнее и находится под NDA):

```
class NonMovable
{
  public:
  NonMovable() = default;
  NonMovable(const NonMovable&) noexcept = default;
  NonMovable(NonMovable&&) noexcept = delete;
  NonMovable& operator=(const NonMovable&) noexcept = default;
  NonMovable& operator=(NonMovable&&) noexcept = delete;
  // ...
};

NonMovable SomeFunction()
{
  NonMovable nonMovable;
  // ...
  return nonMovable;// Error, NonMovalbe(NonMovable&&) is deleted.
}
```

Я не могу понять, почему возникает эта ошибка. У `NonMovable` есть стандартный конструктор копирования, но компилятор пытается вызвать конструктор перемещения, который удален.

Является ли это ошибкой компилятора? Или, может быть, возможен еще какой-то фактор, который принуждает компилятор к такому решению?

Вот так это выглядит. Ошибка наблюдается на разных версиях `Visual Studio` и компиляторов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой стандарт языка используется? Это может быть важным.

Comment: Используется C++17.

Comment: Передача результата из функций реализована всегда переносом. А вы это запретили.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, разве не является перенос просто более предпочтительным, чем копирование, но вовсе не обязательным? Иначе говоря, если перенос возможен - то он выполняется, в противном случае выполняется копирование?

Comment: Ваш класс называется "Не переносимый". Значит передача через стек переносом запрещается в вашем проекте. Остаётся только реализовать в куче с помощью `new`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вероятно, вы путаете правила Java с правилами C++.

Comment: Нет, я пока в стандарте C++14 нахожусь. По-этому такое было у меня наивное мнение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В С++17 ввели правило, по которому для возвращаемых безымянных объектов конструктор копирования или перемещения не должен вызываться и даже не обязан быть объявлен. Это такая обязательная оптимизация (RVO - return value optimization), даже если в теле конструктора выполняется какой-то видимый код. Однако, в вашем случае объект не безымянный (не создан при вызове `return`), а значит, правило RVO не применимо. В данном случае может происходить оптимизация NRVO - Named RVO, но её исполнение не стандартизовано.

Для устранения ошибки в вашем случае можно просто обернуть имя возвращаемой переменной в фигурные скобки, вызвав тем самым конструктор копирования до `return`. Но а при `return` уже сработает обязательная оптимизация RVO:

```
return {nonMovable};
```

Похоже, что вариант с фигурными скобками (list-initialization) не работает должным образом в msvc (по-прежнему хочет вызвать конструктор перемещения), и нужно явно указать вызов копирующего конструктора.

```
return NonMovable(nonMovable);
```

Clang, GCC устраивают оба варианта.

Вообще, стоит заметить, что при наличии копирующего конструктора в классе, автоматической генерации перемещающего конструктора не происходит. Т.е. если убрать эти строки:

```
NonMovable(NonMovable&&) noexcept = delete;
NonMovable& operator=(NonMovable&&) noexcept = delete;
```

класс не станет вдруг перемещаемым, а останется по-прежнему "NonMovable". И в этой ситуации msvc будет вполне корректно себя вести даже с первичным вариантом кода.

Comment: Ага, то есть, все же проблема вызвана особенностями реализации компилятора? Я так и думал!

Comment: Попробовал вариант со скобками - он проблему не решил.

Comment: Удалось, причем при использовании круглых скобок `return NonMovable(nonMovable)`.

Comment: @MGNeo странно, что с фигурными не сработало, по идее вызывается тот же самый конструктор копирования. Можете привести код, который зафейлился с `{}`?

Comment: проверял, в студии не работает с фигурными скобками

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, при использовании фигурных скобок ошибка имеет исходное описание - `Попытка использовать удаленную функцию NonMovable(NonMovable&&)`.

Comment: @MGNeo похоже, тут msvc отличился. В clang/gcc вызывается копирующий конструктор, а msvc хочет мувнуть почему-то.

Answer (score 0):

Если не определить NonMovable(NonMovable&&) явно и не поставить NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = default, то конструктор перемещения не будет создан, а будет использоваться конструктор копирования. = delete применять к конструктору перемещения бессмысленно.

И даже если написать NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = default;
то конструктор копирования по умолчанию будет представлять из себя побайтовое копирование данных.

Можно и нужно эту строку убрать.

Comment: можно. но ведь сделали так не случайно. Иногда нужно явно показать, что вот эти конструкторы/операторы нужны, а вот эти нет.